# Why does view display incorrectly when logged out?

Tags: views, 6

I have a view with a page display configured. When I take a look at the page in the browser, **while logged in**, it displays correctly. When **logged out**, it's a mess: the fields are out of order, the sort order is wrong, the field settings are wrong...

I've built views with this approach dozens of times before and have never experienced this. In fact, I've even built a similar view-based page in the same site with no issues. Any idea what's happening here?!

I've flushed the caches. No role permission settings have been changed beyond the default.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind.

After walking away for an hour or so, coming back and then refreshing the page, **everything is working**. WTF? Does anyone know if this is a Drupal setting somewhere or is it an artifact of the somewhat locked-down instance of Drupal that I have to work with.

Grumble grumble.

Comment: I don't know why this happened, but +1 for using magic to fix it!